# Скрыть параметры запроса

Tags: веб-программирование, запрос

Необходимо совершить переход на страницу, передав параметры. В адресе страницы, на которую совершается переход, не должно быть никаких параметров. При перезагрузке новой страницы должны передаться те же параметры и не должны всплывать какие-либо уведомления (как при POST-запросе).

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Cookies?. . . .

Comment: @andreymal, нельзя, может быть несколько страниц с разными параметрами.

Comment: Куки можно сохранять для отдельных страниц

Comment: @andreymal, возможно, неправильно выразил мысль. Есть страница X и страница Y. Переход идёт со страницы X на страницу Y. Параметры запроса могут меняться. То есть, всего две страницы.

Comment: Если вы хотите открывать одну и ту же страницу несколько раз с разными параметрами одновременно, то это невозможно. Не одновременно - есть куки

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за подсказки. А есть ли способ скрытия окна о переотправке данных c помощью POST-запроса?

Comment: Таки чем вам параметры в адресе не угодили?

Comment: @andreymal, иногда просто неэтично. Хочется добиться красивых адресов везде, где это вохможно.

Comment: @Андрей не забывайте, что люди делятся ссылками. Если в урле не будет параметров определяющих содержимое страницы, то у пользователей могут возникнуть затруднения. Например я нашёл  классную штуку на вашем сайте, скинул ссылку другу, а у него открылась страница без параметров.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, разумеется, есть множество случаев, когда параметры стоит отображать. Но есть и такие ситуации, когда они вовсе необязательны.

Answer (score 0):

И всё-таки решение есть. Производим GET-запрос, с помощью `history.replaceState()` скрываем его параметры и записываем строку запроса. Извлекаем её через `history.state`.

```
// addEventListener() - для Firefox
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var query = history.state;
    if(query === null) {
      history.replaceState(query, 'Page title', './url');
      query = location.search;
      // Исправление для Chrome (если нужно оставить старый заголовок)
      document.title += '_';
      document.title = document.title.substring(0, document.title.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Правда, есть нюанс с обработкой параметров - после обновления страницы они не будут доступны серверу, но будут известны JavaScript. Помимо того, нативная `history.replaceState()` создаёт новую запись в истории браузера, причём не очень красивую (в данный момент ни Chrome, ни Firefox не поддерживают запись второго параметра - заголовка) - вместо названия записывается новый URL.

Судя по всему, корректно `replaceState()` отрабатывает только в [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/).

Помимо того, происходит дублирование истории браузера (если записываем одинаковые названия страниц). Причём одна ссылка в истории будет содержать параметры, а другая - нет.

В качестве ещё одного способа можно предложить отправку пользователя на промежуточную страницу с указанием параметров в GET-запросе. Оттуда перенаправляем с помощью `<meta http-equiv="refresh" ...>` его на нужную страницу, но уже без параметров. И уже на ней смотрим на HTTP Referrer. Плюс такого способа - Referrer доступен и серверу, и клиенту (JavaScript). Минус - сравнительно [невысокая](https://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy) его поддержка. Firefox, насколько удалось понять из экспериментов, вообще не отправляет его, да ещё и записывает в историю адрес страницы с перенаправлением, в отличие от Chrome.